# '!_debugLocked': is not true but only on certain devices

Tags: flutter, debugging, error-handling

I have a complete app I am in the testing stages of.

I can run the app just fine in debug mode on my mobile device, and also the Android Studio emulators - BUT if I try and run the app on my other half's mobile device it shows the red error screen with:

```
'!_debugLocked': is not true
```

I can look in to this (which I think looking at similar problems may be caused by Navigator.pop) but what I don't understand is how the same app can load on my device and an emulator with zero issues, but fails to load, and shows this error, on just on my girlfriend's device?

Both my device and my partners are the same manufacturer, and similar models. Both are only around 1 year old, so both quite current models.

The app was working on her phone until very recently until when I went to load to her phone tonight after a few changes. I have disconnected her phone, connected my phone and reloaded and everything works fine. I then reconnected her phone and tried again - still the same error.

My question is - should and can the app work differently across two devices - load on one and fail on the other?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I was logged in to the app on refresh, where my gf had logged out. Therefore the different states called different page.

In case anyone else stumbles across something similar.